# Why the Deployment Manager wants to deploy more files than necessary?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I determined that the number of files needed for my dummy (2 forms, 1 button, XMLDocument control) application is 4.

- rtl250.bpl
- vcl250.bpl
- vclimg250.bpl
- xmlrtl250.bpl

Why Deployment Manager wants to deploy 15 files, including TeeChart?

Comment: off topic comment but why not create standalone no install exe? that does not need any packages, RTLs nor DLLs (except of winapi) as C++builder/delphi will link them all into exe.

Comment: What does your link to the EMBT site accomplish?  Do you think that anyone who can answer your question will not know what Delphi Tokyo is? And if you're using Delphi Tokyo, why did you include the C++ Builder tag? It's not Delphi Tokyo. Also, there was an existing Delphi 10.2 Tokyo tag here that you should use instead of inventing your own. I've corrected the tags.

Comment: There's no hate (or anger, or rage, or irritation). I simply asked why you went to the trouble to post a  link that adds absolutely no value to your post and simply creates comment noise. And when there are existing tags, you should use them instead of inventing new ones. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and you need  to use them properly so they do what they're supposed to do. Why such thin skin when someone gives you constructive criticism?

Comment: I did change the tag. But if I don't tell you why, how will you learn?

Comment: @KenWhite - I would see the tag edited :) but anyway, thank you for Teaching me.